# How to display images from api in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js, rendering

I am building an ecommerce store with django rest framework and nextjs as the frontend. Thee api has the product data and i want to show product data in nextjs. SO far i can only show the string characters but cannot show the images.  Here's my index.js file.What am i doing wrong?:

```
import react from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Image from 'next/image';

//images from the api in variables
const image1 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/3_Tiny-glass-cup-of-espresso-coffee.jpg'
const image2 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/americano.jpeg'
const image3 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/banana.jpeg'
const image4 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/bigbfast.jpeg'
const image5 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/caffe_latte.jpeg'
const image6 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/cappuccino.jpg'
const image7 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/caramel-latte-image-square.jpg'
const image8 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/choco_lava.jpeg'
const image9 = 'http://localhost:8000/media/media/hot_tea.jpeg'

function Page({stars}) {
    return (
      <div>
      {stars.map((post) => (
 <Card style={{ width: '18rem',float:'right' }} key={post.id}>
  <img src={post.image} width='70' height='70'/>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{post.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      {post.description}
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
      ))}
      </div>
  )
}
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/products')
  const json = await res.json()
  return { stars: json }
}


export default Page
```

Comment: What is the content of starts?

Comment: starts is a variable that i store the http response data from fetch in getInitialProps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.Just needed to add origin. Here's my updated code.

```
 function Page({stars}) {
    const orig = 'http://localhost:8000'
    return (
      <div>
      {stars.map((post) => (
      <>
 <Card style={{ width: '18rem',float:'right',marginRight:'15px',marginBottom:'15px',marginTop:'15px' }} key={post.id}>
  <img src={orig + post.image} width='70' height='70'/>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{post.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      {post.description}
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
</>
      ))}
      </div>
  )
}
```